# Изменение лого в шапке сайта

Tags: html, menu, header

Есть фиксированная прозрачная шапка, белое лого и меню. При скроле вниз от половины высоты 1 блока, шапка становится белой, а логотип должен стать зеленым.
Каким способом можно менять лого в формате png?

Comment: в том же скрипте, который меняет фон шапки, прописываете изменение пути к другой картинке логотипа

Answer (score 0):

Изначально с помощью js или jquery при прокрутке добавим шапке класс `sticky`.

А дальше, например, вариант с css:

```js
// Sticky Header
function navbarFixed() {
  if ($('header').length) {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
      var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

      if (scroll > 100) {
        $('header').addClass("sticky");
      } else {
        $('header').removeClass("sticky");
      }
    });
  }
}
navbarFixed();
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

main {
  background: #eee;
  height: 8000px;
}

header {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  transition: all .2s ease;
}

.logo {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  mask: url(#mymask);
  -webkit-mask-box-image: url(https://developer.spotify.com/assets/branding-guidelines/color2@2x.png);
  background: #fff;
  transition: all .2s ease;
}

header.sticky {
  background: #fff;
}

header.sticky .logo {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>


<header>
  <div class="logo"></div>
  <svg height="0" width="0">
      <mask id="mymask">
        <image id="img" xlink:href="https://developer.spotify.com/assets/branding-guidelines/color2@2x.png" x="0" y="0" height="50px" width="50px" />
      </mask>
    </svg>

</header>

<main></main>
```

Или вариант из комментария все тем же js или jquery меняем путь к логотипу:

```js
// Sticky Header
function navbarFixed() {
  if ($('header').length) {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
      var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

      if (scroll > 100) {
        $('header').addClass("sticky");
        $('.logo').attr('src', 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/0e/Ski_trail_rating_symbol-green_circle.svg/768px-Ski_trail_rating_symbol-green_circle.svg.png');

      } else {
        $('header').removeClass("sticky");
        $('.logo').attr('src', 'https://developer.spotify.com/assets/branding-guidelines/color2@2x.png');

      }
    });
  }
}
navbarFixed();
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

main {
  background: #eee;
  height: 8000px;
}

header {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  transition: all .2s ease;
}

.logo {
  max-height: 100%;
}

header.sticky {
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>


<header>
  <img src="https://developer.spotify.com/assets/branding-guidelines/color2@2x.png" alt="" class="logo">
</header>

<main></main>
```